# Does bottom up heap construction completely depend on the fact that (n+1) is a power of 2?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, complexity-theory, binary-heap

Doesn't bottom up heap construction completely depend on the fact that (n+1) is a power of 2? (where n is the number of nodes).

For example consider the case n = 21. (n +1) is NOT a power of 2- how would this work?

You would create first insert (n+1)/2 nodes or in other words 11 nodes. You would then insert  (n+1)/4 nodes to be the parents of the previously inserted nodes or in other words 5.5 nodes. But how can "half a node" be inserted? **Whenever n is not a power of 2, you always arrive at a decimal amount of node insertions at some level - how do you deal with this?**

I considered removing a certain amount of nodes such that the remaining nodes are a power of two, building a tree out of the remaining nodes and then bubbling the removed nodes into the tree after it has been completed. But with large amounts of nodes this becomes unfeasible: i.e. number of nodes = 1600. The closest power of 2 is 1024, meaning you would have to bubble 576 nodes, which is relatively time consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no requirement that this happens.  Remember that a binary heap may have nodes missing from its final layer.  This means that in the first step, you combine the nodes in a way where you end up with a collection of heaps such that those heaps will form the last two layers of the heap.  Not all of those heaps have to be complete heaps; some of them will have missing children.

If you choose the number of children to omit in a way that the remaining number of nodes is one less than a perfect power of two, you can then proceed with the bottom-up construction as usual.  The result will be a complete binary heap.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! How exactly would you combine the nodes to ensure that you end up with a collection of heaps that form the last two layers of the heap?

Comment: @Riddler- First, determine the largest number k such that 2^k - 1 is less than or equal to the number of nodes.  This number represents the number of nodes that are in the completed part of the tree.  Then, take all the remaining nodes and form them into height-0 trees.  When doing the first merging step, pretend that there are a bunch of "phantom" height-0 trees to make up the balance of the remaining nodes, then merge as usual.  From that point forward, just do normal merging.

Comment: So your basically creating the smallest tree to fit in all the nodes. If there aren't enough nodes to make the complete tree, you are adding in phantom nodes as temporary "placeholders". Am I understanding it correctly?